# How to get data from model class with using SQFlite in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

> > Here I use `SqFlite` functionality with `model class` for data store. But problem is that, when I click on `button`, `addData` method was called null.

> > This is my model class.

```
import 'dart:convert';

DatabaseModel fromJson({String str}) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return DatabaseModel.fromMap(jsonData);
}

String toJson(DatabaseModel databaseModel) {
  final dyn = databaseModel.toMap();
  return json.encode(dyn);
}

class DatabaseModel {
  String id;
  String imageUrl;
  String title;
  String description;
  String newsLink;
  String createDate;
  String category;
  String footerTitle;

  DatabaseModel(
      {this.id,
      this.imageUrl,
      this.title,
      this.description,
      this.newsLink,
      this.createDate,
      this.category,
      this.footerTitle});

  factory DatabaseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DatabaseModel(
      id: json['id'],
      imageUrl: json['imageUrl'],
      title: json['title'],
      description: json['description'],
      newsLink: json['newsLink'],
      createDate: json['createDate'],
      category: json['category'],
      footerTitle: json['footerTitle']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        'id': id,
        'imageUrl': imageUrl,
        'title': title,
        'description': description,
        'newsLink': newsLink,
        'createDate': createDate,
        'category': category,
        'footerTitle': footerTitle
      };
}
```

Now, I display my database class which I use for Add, Delete, and Get data. In this class I use `Model class` because I want to display my data in Bookmark class.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:news_app/src/model/bookmark_db_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseProvider {
//  DatabaseProvider._();

//  static final DatabaseProvider db = DatabaseProvider._();
  Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await getDatabaseInstance();
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> getDatabaseInstance() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(directory.path, 'bookmark.db');
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute('create table Bookmark ('
          'id integer primary key autoincrement,'
          'imageUrl text,'
          'title text,'
          'description text,'
          'newsLink text,'
          'createDate text,'
          'category text,'
          'footerTitle text'
          ')');
    });
  }

  addToDatabase(DatabaseModel databaseModel) async {
    final db = await database;
    var raw = await db.insert('Bookmark', databaseModel.toMap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
    return raw;
  }

  updateDatabase(DatabaseModel databaseModel) async {
    final db = await database;
    var response = await db.update('Bookmark', databaseModel.toMap(),
        where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [databaseModel.id]);
    return response;
  }

  Future<DatabaseModel> getDatabaseModelWithId(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    var response = await db.query('Bookmark', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
    return response.isNotEmpty ? DatabaseModel.fromMap(response.first) : null;
  }

  Future<List<DatabaseModel>> getAllData() async {
    final db = await database;
    var response = await db.query('Bookmark');
    List<DatabaseModel> list =
        response.map((c) => DatabaseModel.fromMap(c)).toList();
    return list;
  }

  deleteDatabase(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    return db.delete('Bookmark', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  deleteAllDatabase() async {
    final db = await database;
    db.delete('Bookmark');
  }
}
```

> > Here I display my BookMark class. This class I use for display data for user.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:news_app/src/model/bookmark_db_provider.dart';
import 'package:news_app/src/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:news_app/src/utils/database.dart';

class BookMark extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BookMarkState createState() => _BookMarkState();
}

class _BookMarkState extends State<BookMark> {
  DatabaseProvider databaseProvider;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseProvider = DatabaseProvider();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage())),
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.color,
            elevation: 0,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              'BookMark News',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FutureBuilder<List<DatabaseModel>>(
                future: databaseProvider.getAllData(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          var common = snapshot.data[index];
                          return Card(
                            elevation: 5.0,
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: SizedBox(
                                height: 85,
                                width: 79,
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                          image:
                                              NetworkImage(common['imageUrl']),
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                ),
                              ),
                              title: Text(common['title']),
                              isThreeLine: true,
                              subtitle: Text(common['footerTitle']),
                              trailing: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(common['createDate']),
                                  Text(common['category'])
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                  } else {}
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              )
              )),
    );
  }
}
```

> > I all of data in Home Page and in this Page when  I pressed on `button` it display `Method was called null`. This type I handle `onclick`.

```
onPressed: () async {
                              print('added data');
                              dbHelper.addToDatabase(DatabaseModel(
                                  imageUrl: allNewsDetail[index]['image_url'],
                                  category: allNewsDetail[index]['category'],
                                  footerTitle: allNewsDetail[index]['footer_title'],
                                  createDate: allNewsDetail[index]['created_date'],
                                  newsLink: allNewsDetail[index]['news_link'],
                                  description: allNewsDetail[index]['description'],
                                  title: allNewsDetail[index]['title']));
                              Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>BookMark()));
                            }
```

When click on button it displays this error.

```
The method 'getAllData' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getAllData()
```

Please check This code I give me solution for it.

Comment: Where are you creating your databaseProvider object?

Comment: I am using databaseProvider object in init method. But data did not display. @Glen

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing in the databaseProvider into this class and that is why you are getting null!

Comment: I updated my code, but still I can not display data.@Glen